# NestJS with CRUD decorator column does not exist

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have a Rest API server using NestJS and typeorm with CRUD decorator on the controllers.
i have a user entity

```
userEntity {
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })
  username: string


  @Column({ nullable: true })
  email: string

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  phone: string

  @PrimaryColumn()
  role: string
}
```

- i know that the username is primary column as well (i have more columns) but i need to identify user by username and role (or id)

and i have another entity (family-info)

```
FamilyInfoEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  familyName: string

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  parentId?: number

  @OneToOne(() => UserEntity, parent => parent.id, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  parent?: UserEntity
}
```

but i get an error "column FamilyInfoEntity.parent_username does not exist"
when I'm trying to get all family-info (localhost:3000/api/family-info)

my DB is empty, no rows on user table, and no rows on family-info table...
bot i don't think it's the issue

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mark each class with the `@Entity()` annotation

````
@Entity()
class FamilyInfoEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  familyName: string

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  parentId?: number

  @OneToOne(() => UserEntity, parent => parent.id, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn()
  parent?: UserEntity
} ```
````